# jQuery Parsing Simple XML as part of Ajax Request

Tags: xml, jquery, jquery-selectors, xml-parsing

I'm looking to parse errors that are returned by my server in xml after an unsuccessful ajax request. The xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>Full name can't be blank</error>
  <error>Email can't be blank</error>
</errors>
```

I am simply trying to build a ul tag from the xml with an li tag for each error in the xml response. The response should be processed in a way which outputs this HTML and appends it to a div with the id of "contactErrors":

```
<ul>
   <li>Full name can't be blank</li>
   <li>Email can't be blank</li>
</ul>
```

Currently I have the following jQuery, but I cannot figure out how to parse the HTTP 422 (form errors/unprocessable entity) response properly.

```
$("#new_message").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "messages.xml",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        statusCode: {
            201: function(data) {
                $("#new_message").slideUp();
                $("#contactSuccess").fadeIn(2500);
            },
            422: function(data) {
                // XML response should be processed here and can be accessed by calling $(data)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I recommend using JSON instead of XML for this kind of stuff

Comment: I was considering JSON but haven't the slightest idea how to parse it either :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not JSon? For XML you can return XML in your action with

```
  return this.Content(xmlStringValue, "text/xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is more suited for server client communication. On server side you can encode an object to JSON in PHP with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), in ASP.NET using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and so on. You can find a complete list on [json.org](http://www.json.org/) (scroll down). Parsing it is very simple, because it is a valid javascript code, you only need to eval it.

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

If you want to write JSON yourself think of it as a normal javascript object, which contains members with values, which can be numbers, boolean, arrays or string.